# Google maps zoom, need to zoom near marker which is not happening instead its zooming to center point

Tags: javascript, google-maps

i am trying to zoom my google map to a place where i push a marker on to the map.... but if i increase the zoom value in map it is zooming to the center point of map instead of the place where marker is placed... so can u please let me know... where am i going wrong... !! i tried many ways like map.setzoom and all to increase zoom near place where i push marker but its zooming to center point... please help!! here is the javascript:

```
    function init() {
        var answers = new Array();
        var data = document.getElementById('Hidden1').value;

        var pairs = data.split('@');
        for (var i = 0; i < pairs.length - 1; i++) {
            var pair = pairs[i];
            var pairs1 = pair.split(',');
            answers[i] = pairs1;
        }

        var locations = answers;

        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
            zoom: 1,
            center: new google.maps.LatLng(12.9715987, 77.5945627),
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        });

        var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();

        var marker, i;

        for (i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {

            marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                position: new google.maps.LatLng(locations[i][1], locations[i][2]),
                map: map
            });

            google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function(marker, i) {
                return function() {
                    infowindow.setContent(locations[i][0]);
                    infowindow.open(map, marker);
                }
            })(marker, i));
        }
        map.setZoom(14);
        document.getElementById('dvloading5').style.display = 'none';
        document.getElementById('map').style.display = 'block';
    }
```

the div in which i display map is a small one... and code is as follows:

```
    <div id="map" style="width: 485px; height: 450px">
    </div>
```

is it because div size of map small that zoom is not happening properly?? or code issue please let me know...!! Thanking you in advance!!

Answer (score 0):

You should use `google.maps.LatLngBounds()` to get the functionality.

Create a bounds variable-

```
var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
```

Then in your loop (*modified for clarity*)-

```
for (i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) 
  {
      var lat = parseFloat(locations[i][1]);
      var lng = parseFloat(locations[i][2]);
      var pos = new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng);
      marker = new google.maps.Marker({position: new google.maps.LatLng(pos),map: map});
      bounds.extend(pos);
   }
 map.fitBounds(bounds);
```